# Scala @ IntelliJ 12 - Can't fetch docs / some functions are not shown in dropdown. [BUGS]

Tags: scala, ide, intellij-idea

I've been searching for a long time now to find a decent IDE for Scala.
Eclipse is not satisfying at all, as auto completion doesn't work, somehow. Also, I can't modify the libraries at all in the build path e.g. set the docs/source.
IntelliJ seems better, however, there are some major bugs:
When the drop down menu appears that lists all the function, some of them are sometimes just not shown! I think it's because of scala-library / scala-compiler, it mixes them up or something... [image: odd]

The docs cannot be fetched, I get this message over and over again (here the functions are listed, strange enough...):
[image: dysfunction]

This is the library window:
[image: Bug]

The dependencies and the compiler are set right, I strongly suppose.

Does anyone know what the problem is? And how to fix it? Or is it a known bug?

Is there an IDE that can handle Scala?

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution to the problem:

The bug was caused by Java Decompiler Plugin. It tried to decompile the binaries of Scala's class-files, which obviously failed. This led to that error message and further led to the Scala plugin not working as it should, thus not displaying some of the functions.

This took me a long time to figure out, I installed 2 other versions of IntelliJ (which apparently imported the JD plugin), NetBeans and downloaded several builds of the Scala Plugin, only to discover this cause. Deactivating Java Decompiler solved it.

Regards.

Comment: I've tried disabling the Java Bytecode Decompiler plugin without success... I'll update if I find something that does work, but I'm not sure this is the solution by itself. [edit] just realised how old this question is, I'm on IntelliJ 14 so no reason it would necessarily be the same

Answer (score 1):

Typically, searching for names (values/classes/functions/etc.) for auto-complete can be quite slow compared to Java in IntelliJ simply because the automatically imported namespace can be quite large, and it also searches through all implicit conversions. However, I've never seen it refuse to show functions like your screenshot, what version of IntelliJ and Scala plugin are you using?

I've never gotten the pop-up docs to work via attaching JavaDocs (I haven't tried remote fetching), so I'd recommend just ctrl+click to go through to the source to read the documentation there. (However, the function/type definition does popup correctly when sources are attached). I'd suggest posting an issue at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL if you have the opportunity.

To your final question, the answer is unfortunately no. The tooling for Scala is nowhere near that of Java, but both Scala IDE for Eclipse and IntelliJ are making great progress in changing that, and both are strong in some areas while weak in others. In the end, you'll get limited support either way, so choose whichever fits you best.

Comment: I have found the solution, I added the answer below. Thanks for the help though - the documentations and all work perfectly now!